# Combining String and Random Int in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, string

I have a function that returns a random integer

```
async getRandomInt(min: number, max: number) {
    var min = Math.ceil(min);
    var max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); 
  }
```

I am trying to use the return value in a string

```
async addApiName(){
    var randInt = this.getRandomInt(100,2000)
    var name = "Test_" + randInt
}
```

But this is returning "Test_[object.promise]

Comment: await this.getRandomInt(100,2000). Try this. 
Also, do you know why we use async? You should not just them everywhere

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed to convert `ToString()` and then it worked.  I am using async because this is Playwright code where it's needed.  This was just a small snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use async when working with promises in this case, you don't need it, removing the async keyword will meet your needs.

```
getRandomInt(min: number, max: number) {
    var min = Math.ceil(min);
    var max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); 
}
```

[image]

[image]